# Controlling image displayed when a page is liked

Tags: image, facebook-like

Please pardon my ignorance, I'm a website visual designer, not a programmer (let the flames begin!):

Following Facebook's instructions, I just added the iFrame like button code to a site that I'm working on, and it seems to work, BUT the image which displays on my wall (once the Like is posted) seems to be of a random image (could be anything, from a button to a spacer to whatever!) inside the external site which I'm liking from. How do I control which image appears on a member's FB wall when they hit the like button?

Comment: Your question needs more detail.  Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, when dealing with this sort of issue with the LIKE button its less an issue of what code is used and more an issue of what code is lacking.  Meta tags in this case :)

Comment: @Lix, code could either be the html of the meta tags as well as the html of the like button.  Harvey, I believe, was asking for both. I do like your detailed answer below, props for that!

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can view the source code at www.crossroadsnursery.com. I'm pretty sick and disgusted with this ordeal...something that should be simple is now completely discombobulated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look into is [Open Graph og:meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).  These tags help Facebook to decide:

- what image to display
- what text to use as the title
- what text to use for the  description
- and more...

The tags look something like this (taken from the link above):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
               a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
               threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
               weapons."/>
```

You will have to substitute *your* values for the values in the example here.
On the [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) where you most likely got your code from, it mentions the open graph protocol and its importance with relation to the like button.  Scroll down a bit further and you'll see there is a "step 2" in the process of implementing a Facebook "like" button.

Comment: I just posted the meta tags generated on the Like button page and still nothing seems to be working. In looking at the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ page, I noticed that there is this code:

Comment: Let's try this again (timed out):

Comment: And again:
I just posted the meta tags generated on the Like button page and still nothing seems to be working (other than the counter working and FB users getting the errant image and description). In looking at the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ page, I noticed that there is this code: 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
is this needed too? You can see the page I'm adding the code to by going to njlandscaping.com. Perhaps you have a suggestion as to what I need to do?

Comment: Oops, the URL for the site in question is http://www.crossroadsnursery.com. Sorry, I'm bad at multitasking!

Comment: Tried it, now something's really messed up. The Like button disappeared and is subbed with something else. I was NOT made for programming!

Comment: Picked up fresh code for the Like button and it reappeared...ok, now back to the original problem...why isn't this OG meta tag thing working? Check the source code at http://www.crossroadsnursery.com. Many many thanks from this "code idiot"!

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, but I'm still hanging here. If you can't follow up on this, can you recommend someone I can go to get an answer? I have a client that's dependent on getting this problem solved. FB support seems to be non-existant outside of this forum. Sorry to be a pain --- I figure that you have bigger fish to fry. But I am truly stuck!

Comment: Ok - what you want to do is force Facebook to "re-scan" your URL - you can do that by feeding your URL (www.crossroadsnursery.com) to the Facebook Debugger - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Ahhh, there it is! THANK YOU...and hopefully I'll have the time and patience to learn this stuff. Many many many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help my friend!  If you feel that my answer helped you out then consider marking it as answered :)